# "By" or without "by"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Are these correct sentences and can they be with or without "by"?

> A child is someone who can call a duck a goose.
>
> A child is someone who can call a duck by a goose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct.  The second is not.

Ordinarily I would try and elaborate this answer with some attempt at creating a similar, but valid, sentence featuring "by", and explaining the difference in meaning from the first.  However, in this case I can't envisage any similar sentence with "by", so I'm afraid I can think of nothing further to add.

Comment: it can be said like that but it's weird, and it doesn't mean the first one, right? A child is someone who can be called a duck by a goose.

Comment: "A child is someone who can be called a duck by a goose" -- yes that is a correct sentence.  It means something very different from the first though.  In "A child is someone who can call a duck a goose", the child calls a duck a goose.  In "A child is someone who can be called a duck by a goose", the goose calls the child a duck.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a duck a goose.

You can call a duck Henry

You can call a duck by the name (of) Henry

You can call a duck by the name of a goose.

You can call a duck by its own name, or by your brother's name.

You can call a duck by a rude name.

So *call ... by ...* is used only when what follows the "by" is phrase that contains the word "name". (Probably also with a synonym of "name").